# fastcgi php nginx errorlog messed up

Tags: nginx, error-handling, php7, fastcgi

I have a strange problem, the errorlog of my nginx server is somehow messed up: PHP errors seem to be all written in one line and repeating itself recursively. This way the llog grows a few GB within one day!

This is **one line** in the error log:

```
2020/03/26 16:58:45 [error] 29816#29816: *32 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: SCRIPT_FILENAME in /var/kunden/webs/my_web_app/www/pics/userpics/index.php on line 58PHP message: PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: pfad in /var/kunden/webs/my_web_app/www/pics/userpics/index.php on line 60PHP message: PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 1 in /var/kunden/webs/my_web_app/www/pics/userpics/index.php on line 65PHP message: PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: benutzer in /var/kunden/webs/my_web_app/www/pics/userpics/index.php on line 70PHP message: PHP Notice:  Undefined index: PATH_TRANSLATED in /var/kunden/webs/my_web_app/www/pics/userpics/index.php on line 84PHP message: PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: localdir in /var/kunden/webs/my_web_app/www/pics/userpics/index.php on line 96PHP message: PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: localdir in /var/kunden/webs/my_web_app/www/pics/userpics/index.php on line 96PHP message: PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: localdir in /var/kunden/webs/my_web_app/www/pics/userpics/index.php on line 96PHP message: PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: localdir in /var/kunden/webs/my_web_app/www/pics/userpics/index.php on line 96PHP message: PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: localdir in /var/kunden/webs/my_web_app/www/pics/userpics/index.php on line 96PHP message: PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: localdir in /var/kunden/webs/my_web_app/www/pics/userpics/index.php on line 96PHP message: PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: localdir in /var/kunden/webs/my_web_app/www/pics/userpics/index.php on line 96PHP message: PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: localdir in /var/kunden/webs/my_web_app/www/pics/userpics/index.php on line 96PHP message: PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: localdir in /var/kunden/webs/my_web_app/www/pics/userpics/index.php on line 96PHP message: PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: localdir in /var/kunden/webs/my_web_app/www/pics/userpics/index.php on line 96PHP message: PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: localdir in /var/kunden/webs/my_web_app/www/pics/userpics/index.php on li
```

The lines are cut after 2048 characters.

here i split the lines before each new error:

```
2020/03/26 16:58:45 [error] 29816#29816: *32 FastCGI sent in stderr: "
PHP message: PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: SCRIPT_FILENAME in /var/kunden/webs/my_web_app/www/pics/userpics/index.php on line 58
PHP message: PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: pfad in /var/kunden/webs/my_web_app/www/pics/userpics/index.php on line 60
PHP message: PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 1 in /var/kunden/webs/my_web_app/www/pics/userpics/index.php on line 65
PHP message: PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: benutzer in /var/kunden/webs/my_web_app/www/pics/userpics/index.php on line 70
PHP message: PHP Notice:  Undefined index: PATH_TRANSLATED in /var/kunden/webs/my_web_app/www/pics/userpics/index.php on line 84
PHP message: PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: localdir in /var/kunden/webs/my_web_app/www/pics/userpics/index.php on line 96
PHP message: PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: localdir in /var/kunden/webs/my_web_app/www/pics/userpics/index.php on line 96
PHP message: PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: localdir in /var/kunden/webs/my_web_app/www/pics/userpics/index.php on line 96
PHP message: PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: localdir in /var/kunden/webs/my_web_app/www/pics/userpics/index.php on line 96
PHP message: PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: localdir in /var/kunden/webs/my_web_app/www/pics/userpics/index.php on line 96
PHP message: PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: localdir in /var/kunden/webs/my_web_app/www/pics/userpics/index.php on line 96
PHP message: PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: localdir in /var/kunden/webs/my_web_app/www/pics/userpics/index.php on line 96
PHP message: PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: localdir in /var/kunden/webs/my_web_app/www/pics/userpics/index.php on line 96
PHP message: PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: localdir in /var/kunden/webs/my_web_app/www/pics/userpics/index.php on line 96
PHP message: PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: localdir in /var/kunden/webs/my_web_app/www/pics/userpics/index.php on line 96
PHP message: PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: localdir in /var/kunden/webs/my_web_app/www/pics/userpics/index.php on li
```

Where could this come from? how do I have to define a standard error reporting in nginx?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like nginx with fastcgi bundles all errors, that occur on one page in the message of one line.

If a script has so many errors  (probably due to a PHP upgrade) then the line is truncated at 2048 chars.